# Validating before accepting the data

Tags: validation, excel, excel-formula, vba

In Excel can I validate a cell checking whether it meets the criteria as required?

For example, I want to allow users input data only if it is properly input into the system. The criteria are:

```
Text length should be 12,  
it should start with 27 and  
it should end with V.
```

Please help in order to validate whether the user that has input the data properly or not.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for vba

Just use this built in feature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

That is it.

For more info, Google it and you will find tons of references.